# One who hates his own image

Tags: single-word-requests

Let us pretend the 'one who hates his own image' is a 'selfie-loather'.
If so, a sentence incorporating the term could be

> He always said he hated mirrors and I had assumed he was a 
>   'selfie-loather' so I was shocked when I saw him apparently
>   admiring his face in the glass!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want? 'Self-loathed' works, so what is it you don't like about it?

Comment: I think you mean *self-loather* and not **selfie-loather**?! Don't you?

Comment: [Wikipedia article on _Self-hated_.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hatred) Related thread, [_Is there a single word that describes someone who hates themself? (Antonym of narcissist)_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258849/is-there-a-single-word-that-describes-someone-who-hates-themself-antonym-of-na)

Comment: If there were an antonym for the literal definition of narcissist, that would work, but the literal definition has gotten lost.

Comment: Do we have enough context that can generate and support any answer to this question? The OP is not responding to @mitch's comment.

Comment: The word you are looking for is "normal". Every person hates their own image to an extent.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy I don't think it is a typo. He means 'selfie-loather'. As in someone who hates having pictures taken of themselves.

Comment: There's a very simple solution, if there is indeed anyone who is a selfie-loather.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a 'selfie-loather' hates seeing everyone's lame selfies on social media.

Answer (score 6):

> [**This body-image death spiral ends at universal self-hatred**](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2012/may/30/body-image-mps-report-narcissim)
>
> "Up to one in five cosmetic surgery patients could suffer from body dysmorphic disorder" – again, the definition is sloppy. **Body dysmorphic disorder is the irrational hatred of your body**. You could easily argue that everybody having cosmetic surgery for reasons other than physical comfort has body dysmorphic disorder, just because it's irrational to hate yourself so much that you'd ask anyone to slice into you. Or you could argue that hating yourself that much is a maladaptive but understandable response to the pressures of your cultural environment.

Source: *The Guardian*

> **[Body Dysmorphic Disorder (BDD)](http://www.adaa.org/understanding-anxiety/related-illnesses/other-related-conditions/body-dysmorphic-disorder-bdd)**
>
> But people who have body dysmorphic disorder (BDD) think about their real or perceived flaws for hours each day.
>
> They can't control their negative thoughts and don't believe people who tell them that they look fine. Their thoughts may cause severe emotional distress and interfere with their daily functioning. They may miss work or school, avoid social situations and isolate themselves, even from family and friends, because they fear others will notice their flaws.
>
> **They may even undergo unnecessary plastic surgeries to correct perceived imperfections, never finding satisfaction with the results**.

Source: ADAA (Anxiety and Depression Association of America)

Comment: Yes to *dysmorphia*. I was about to suggest the very word but then saw how well this answer covers it.

Comment: @human The only problem is there is no context in the question or the question is confusing.

Answer (score 5):

[Eisoptrophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisoptrophobia) is the psychological condition of loathing to see one's own image, to see oneself in the mirror.  Incidentally, this is distinct from  [spectrophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrophobia), which is the fear of mirrors.

Comment: Usually phobias express irrational fears not self-disgust.

Comment: *Eisoptrophobia is being scared of one's own reflection* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisoptrophobia

Comment: And *[Eisoptrophobia](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=12252): An abnormal and persistent fear of mirrors. Sufferers experience undue anxiety even though they realize their fear is irrational. Because their fear often is grounded in superstitions, they may worry that breaking a mirror will bring bad luck or that looking into a mirror will put them in contact with a supernatural world inside the glass.*

Comment: @Mari-Lou A : Actually, phobia is a bit of a catch-all.  Photophobia isn't a fear of light, but an physiological reaction to it.  Homophobia isn't the fear of homosexuals but a disliking of homosexuals.

Comment: I can't find a definition that supports yours, here's another : [Eisoptrophobia is the fear of mirrors or of seeing oneself in a mirror The origin of the word *eisoptro* is Greek (meaning mirror) and phobia is Greek (meaning fear).](http://common-phobias.com/Eisoptro/phobia.htm) *This fear could have developed in the early history, when people used to use ponds and still waters as mirrors (or looking glasses). People believed the images they saw in the water were their souls looking back at them and it frighten them.* And **(rare) Fear of seeing one’s reflection in a mirror**. Wiktionary

Comment: See: Diagnostic and Statistical Manual of Mental Disorders (4th Ed.), 2004, American Psychiatric Association, Washington, DC.  It's not online but an actual book open beside me.  I have a BS in psychology and MS in clinical psychology.

Comment: Then how can I possibly see it? Please support your answer with external references.

Comment: Today is a record day for incompetent edits, I have never seen so many poor approvals in the three years I have been a member. The Wikipedia link, which I quoted from, says nothing about "psychological condition of loathing". This last edit, 4th,  I must stress, has nothing to do with Harma but it *did* correct quite a number of typos.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Fear and hatred are closely related. “Fear is the path to the dark side. Fear leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering.” - Yoda.

Comment: @Mari-LouA For another view, go here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CQg9f7z9eg

Comment: @Zenadix Let's say I hate black olives, does it mean [I'm scared of eating them?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272932/is-there-a-name-for-fear-of-olives-in-english) Do I do everything humanly possible to avoid seeing or even smelling  their presence? Do I break out in a cold sweat if I see a person eating a black olive? I can hate, or strongly dislike something without it developing into a phobia.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Phobias usually refer to extreme aversion. A mild dislike isn't necessarily a phobia. But feeling mild dislike still involves feeling mild fear.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If fear leads to anger, and anger leads to hate, that does NOT mean that fear is the *only* path to hatred. It also does NOT imply that there is a two way street. Fear leading to anger does not mean that anger leads to fear. Anger leading to hatred does not mean that hatred leads to anger. More importantly, phobia has other connotations besides irrational fears. "phobia may also refer to conditions other than true phobias. [...]hydrophobia is an old name for rabies [...] photophobia usually refers to a physical complaint, rather than an irrational fear of light"

Answer (score 3):

No need to get clinical about this answer. We have a perfectly good agent noun, 'self-hater', formed from 'self-hatred' (= 'self-hate'):

> **self-hatred** *n.*
>   Hatred of oneself, esp. of one's actual self when contrasted with one's imagined self.

["self-ˈhatred, n.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/175271 (accessed January 08, 2016).]

As the "esp." highlights, the hatred may be of an *actual self* contrasted with an *imagined self*. So, 'self-hater' works well in the OP's example:

> He always said he hated mirrors and I had assumed he was a **self-hater**, so I was shocked when I saw him apparently admiring his face in the glass!

It should be stipulated, however, that what the subject of the example saw in the "glass" might've been something considerably stronger and more admirable than himself.

Comment: Better than listing unfamiliar words.

Comment: +1 _No need to get clinical about this answer_. Furthermore there is never such a need. Leveraging clinical conditions, especially on a language asset with no expertise on the subject matter, especially to stereotype people, worst, because such people wouldn't like selfies or something as trivial, is just inappropriate and wrong. Making a diagnosis is also a reserved act. Thank you for an answer on language.